# How can I use a Command to activate livereload in reload

Tags: ionic2, livereload

I'm trying to figure out what are the commands or ways to reload my browser platform on every change detected with ionic or cordova because for me this lineis not working:

```
ionic run browser --livereload
```

So I'm wondering if you know how to do that. I'm using cordova plugins by the way.

Kind regards!

Comment: I think what you are looking for is ionic serve -lc. You can see more information here https://ionicframework.com/docs/v2/cli/

Comment: That command only works if you don't have any cordova plugin installed.

Comment: The command is correct and their github commits indicate that it should reload and serve cordova plugins. Maybe submit an issue to their github

Answer (score 0):

You can start your app in your browser with

`ionic serve`

This will refresh the app after every save. There were some build changes after the ionic rc2 release, so be sure to update to the latest version. That way it will even show you a loading toast, as well as give you a nicely formatted js error whenever your app fails to launch.

To update your project to the latest build version, update your package.json

```
{
  ...
  "scripts": {
    "clean": "ionic-app-scripts clean",
    "build": "ionic-app-scripts build",
    "ionic:build": "ionic-app-scripts build",
    "ionic:serve": "ionic-app-scripts serve"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    ...
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@ionic/app-scripts": "0.0.47",
    "typescript": "2.0.9"
  }
}
```

You can find an example of a full package.json here: https://github.com/driftyco/ionic2-app-base

Comment: Sorry but those commands only work if you don't have any cordova plugin installed.

Comment: It also works when you have plugins installed, but you obviously can't use the plugins themselves. If you get an error because of something cordova related, try wrapping that code in an `if(platform.is('cordova')) { ... }` as described here: https://ionicframework.com/docs/v2/api/platform/Platform/

Comment: No, I'm not receiving any error.. I can use the plugins correctly running `ionic run browser` but on every change made I need to stop that command and run it again.

Comment: If you run `ionic run browser`, does it run on your PCs browser or on your phone?

Comment: On my PCs browser

Comment: According to the docs, `ionic run` should run the app on the specified platform, which can be either android or ios. So I'm surprised this works. Is there any difference in running `ionic serve` and `ionic run browser`? Because cordova plugins have to be run on either ios or android, I can't imagine that they work in the browser in any case. http://ionicframework.com/docs/v2/cli/run/

Comment: It's possible to run in the browser and many other platforms.. in the browser is to accelerate the development process and avoid compile/install on the app every time you change something... but only runing `ionic run browser` or `cordova run browser`... `ionic serve` only works when you don't have any cordova plugin in use.

Comment: Ok, so I read about the usage of ionic run browser. It looks like this includes cordova.js and adds all plugins that have browser support. I didn't know this is possible. The question still remains if you need those cordova plugins in the browser. If you are just testing the app, you can mock the data you expect from the plugins using the method I showed you above. I developed a number of ionic2 apps and this method has worked great so far. But back to your question, might it be related to this? https://github.com/driftyco/ionic-app-scripts/issues/599

Answer (score 0):

ionic serve is working fine for me.
for browser, ionic serve detect every change in code and refresh the page.

You can find some commands here:
https://ionicframework.com/docs/cli/serve/

Comment: While this may answer the question, 
[it would be preferable](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/8259) to include the 
essential parts of the answer here, and provide the link for reference.

Answer (score 0):

on Cli, you may try *npm run dev* too. --> Runs ionic serve ( development ). it's short, concise, gets the job done most times. give it a try